# Unable to load tidyverse in rstudio cloud

Tags: r, rstudio, tidyverse

unable to load tidyverse in rstudio cloud. I am getting the  error below, i tried to remove rlang and tidyverse and then again reinstalled it but the problem persists. Could you please help? many thanks.

```
library(tidyverse)
#> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'tidyverse' in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
#>  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.5.9000 is required
```

subsequently i was able to update the rlang with the following command however the rlang is not working with the error pasted below.

```
devtools::install_github("r-lib/rlang", build_vignettes = TRUE)

sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
#> Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
#> Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3.0
#> LAPACK: /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3.0
#> 
#> locale:
#>  [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8       
#>  [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8   
#>  [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C          
#> [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] compiler_3.6.0   magrittr_1.5     tools_3.6.0      htmltools_0.4.0 
#>  [5] yaml_2.2.1       Rcpp_1.0.4       stringi_1.4.6    rmarkdown_1.13  
#>  [9] highr_0.8        knitr_1.23       stringr_1.4.0    xfun_0.7        
#> [13] digest_0.6.25    rlang_0.4.5.9000 evaluate_0.14
Created on 2020-04-27 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)

However when i loading the rlang using the library(rlang) I am getting the error.

library(rlang)
Error in value[3L] :
Package ‘rlang’ version 0.4.5 cannot be unloaded:
Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘rlang’ is imported by ‘vctrs’, ‘testthat’, ‘reprex’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘ellipsis’, ‘usethis’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘tibble’, ‘tidyquant’, ‘htmltools’, ‘pillar’, ‘pkgload’ so cannot be unloaded
and the above error with loading the tidyverse continues.
```

Comment: Did you restart your R session before installing `rlang`?

Comment: thanks Phil, restarting the rcloud session worked:)